# MySQL: Combining multiple columns from Table 1 and inserting into 1 column in Table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

I've been trying to figure this out, but can't seem to come up with a simple solution.

Say for instance I have a table that has similar data throughout 3 columns (i.e. different types of activities spanning 3 columns) but I want to have those three columns inserted into a separate table (Table2) so I can keep the like data together and perform a JOIN to match it with its respective data in Table1.

I'm not talking about performing a CONCAT or CONCAT_WS, but moving those three columns from Table1 into one column in Table2, each item with its own row.

Is there a way to do this through a query without having to manually insert each entry into Table2?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you looking for a trigger or trying to insert data into two tables with one query.  It's possible with a trigger, but an insert statement can't affect two tables at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It might be as simple as:

```
insert into table2
(field)
select column1 from table1
union
select column2 from table1
union
select column3 from table1
```

But, before you do this, decide what you want to do if two columns in table1 have the same value.